# site server denying access to the associated php parse file of an onClick jquery $.post()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, server

I have a basic onClick jquery $.post() being used in a wordpress plugin I am developing that is being denied to the associated php file by the site server.

**Here is the jQuery:**

```
$('.pnb-min').click(function(){     
        var folder = $(this).data('folder');
        var url = 'url to parsing file';
        var postit = $.post( url, {folder:folder});
        postit.done(function( data ) {alert(data);});       
    });
```

**... and the triggering html**

```
<li id="" style="cursor:pointer;" class="pnb-min  pnb-expand" data-folder="css">Refresh Stylesheets</li>
```

**... and the php parsing file:**

```
<?php 

    # header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://s8w.org/wp-content/plugins/pnbWidgets/widgets/file-manager/dashboard.page.php,Vary: Origin');
    
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://s8w.org/wp-admin/admin.php?page=file-manager-dashboard,Vary: Origin');
    
    # header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');


    
    /* CODE MINIMIZER
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
    defined('ABSPATH') or die ('You are not authorized to access this script.');
    $asbP = ABSPATH . 'wp-content/plugins/pnbWidgets/core/';
    $asbU = 'https://s8w.org/wp-content/plugins/pnbWidgets/core/'; 
    
    
    /* aquire folder to minimize from jquery post on button click
    ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
    $folder = $_POST['which'];
    
    /* get code
    ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
    #initialize vars
    $common_styles = ''; $admin_styles = ''; $common_js = ''; $admin_js = ''; $common_js = ''; $admin_js = '';
    
    # common styles
    foreach(glob($asbP . '/css/common/*.css') as $file) {$common_styles .= file_get_contents($file);}
    # admin styles
    foreach(glob($asbP . '/css/admin/*.css') as $file) {$admin_styles .= file_get_contents($file);}
    # common jquery
    foreach(glob($asbP . '/js/common/*.php') as $file) {$common_js .= file_get_contents($file);}
    # admin jquery
    foreach(glob($asbP . '/js/admin/*.php') as $file) {$admin_js .= file_get_contents($file);}
    # common functions
    foreach(glob($asbP . '/functions/common/*.php') as $file) {$common_js .= file_get_contents($file);}
    # admin functions
    foreach(glob($asbP . '/functions/admin/*.php') as $file) {$admin_js .= file_get_contents($file);}   
    
    /* stylesheets
    ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
    if($folder == 'css'){
        
        # minimize common styles
        $code = str_replace('/*',"~",str_replace('*/',"~",$common_styles)); preg_match_all("'~(.*?)~'si", $code, $match);
        foreach($match[1] as $val) {$this_code = '~'.$val.'~';$code = str_replace($this_code,"",$code);}        
        $code = str_replace("\r","",str_replace("\n","",str_replace("\t","",$code)));
        $common_styles_min = $code;
        
        # minimize admin styles
        $code = str_replace('/*',"~",str_replace('*/',"~",$admin_styles)); preg_match_all("'~(.*?)~'si", $code, $match);
        foreach($match[1] as $val) {$this_code = '~'.$val.'~';$code = str_replace($this_code,"",$code);}        
        $code = str_replace("\r","",str_replace("\n","",str_replace("\t","",$code)));
        $admin_styles_min = $common_styles_min.$code; $admin_styles = $common_styles.$admin_styles;
        
        $url = $asbU.'css/';
        
        # backup existing files
        copy($url.'common.css', $url.'backup/common-bu.css');
        copy($url.'common-min.css', $url.'backup/common.min-bu.css');
        copy($url.'admin.css', $url.'backup/admin-bu.css');
        copy($url.'admin-min.css', $url.'backup/admin.min-bu.css');
        
        # write common stylesheets
        $handle = fopen($url.'common.css', 'w+'); fwrite($handle, $common_styles); fclose($handle); 
        $handle = fopen($url.'common.min.css', 'w+'); fwrite($handle, $common_styles_min); fclose($handle);
        
        # write admin stylesheets
        $handle = fopen($url.'admin.css', 'w+'); fwrite($handle, $admin_styles); fclose($handle);   
        $handle = fopen($url.'admin.min.css', 'w+'); fwrite($handle, $admin_styles_min); fclose($handle);
        
        
        $msg = 'All stylesheets have been updated.'; 
        
    }
    
    /* jQuery
    ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
    if($folder == 'js'){
        
        # minimize common js
        $code = str_replace('/*',"~",str_replace('*/',"~",$common_js)); preg_match_all("'~(.*?)~'si", $code, $match);
        foreach($match[1] as $val) {$this_code = '~'.$val.'~';$code = str_replace($this_code,"",$code);}        
        $code = str_replace("\r","",str_replace("\n","",str_replace("\t","",$code)));
        $common_js_min = $code;
        
        # minimize admin js
        $code = str_replace('/*',"~",str_replace('*/',"~",$admin_js)); preg_match_all("'~(.*?)~'si", $code, $match);
        foreach($match[1] as $val) {$this_code = '~'.$val.'~';$code = str_replace($this_code,"",$code);}        
        $code = str_replace("\r","",str_replace("\n","",str_replace("\t","",$code)));
        $admin_js_min = $common_js_min.$code;
        $admin_js = $common_js.$admin_js;
        
        $url = $asbU.'js/';
        
        # backup existing files
        copy($url.'common.php', $url.'backup/common-bu.php');
        copy($url.'common-min.php', $url.'backup/common.min-bu.php');
        copy($url.'admin.php', $url.'backup/admin-bu.php');
        copy($url.'admin-min.php', $url.'backup/admin.min-bu.php');
        
        # write common jQuery
        $handle = fopen($url.'common.js', 'w+'); fwrite($handle, $common_js); fclose($handle);  
        $handle = fopen($url.'common.min.js', 'w+'); fwrite($handle, $common_js_min); fclose($handle);
        
        # write admin jQuery
        $handle = fopen($url.'admin.js', 'w+'); fwrite($handle, $admin_js); fclose($handle);    
        $handle = fopen($url.'admin.min.js', 'w+'); fwrite($handle, $admin_js_min); fclose($handle);
        
        
        $msg = 'All jQuery files have been updated.';
    }
    
    /* js
    ---------------------------------------------------------------- */
    if($folder == 'functions'){     
        
        # minimize common functions
        $code = str_replace('/*',"~",str_replace('*/',"~",$common_functions)); preg_match_all("'~(.*?)~'si", $code, $match);
        foreach($match[1] as $val) {$this_code = '~'.$val.'~';$code = str_replace($this_code,"",$code);}        
        $code = str_replace("\r","",str_replace("\n","",str_replace("\t","",$code)));
        $common_functions_min = $code;
        
        # minimize admin functions
        $code = str_replace('/*',"~",str_replace('*/',"~",$admin_functions)); preg_match_all("'~(.*?)~'si", $code, $match);
        foreach($match[1] as $val) {$this_code = '~'.$val.'~';$code = str_replace($this_code,"",$code);}        
        $code = str_replace("\r","",str_replace("\n","",str_replace("\t","",$code)));
        $admin_functions_min = $common_functions_min.$code;
        $admin_functions = $common_functions.$admin_functions;
        
        $url = $asbU.'functions/';
        
        # backup existing files
        copy($url.'common.php', $url.'backup/common-bu.php');
        copy($url.'common-min.php', $url.'backup/common.min-bu.php');
        copy($url.'admin.php', $url.'backup/admin-bu.php');
        copy($url.'admin-min.php', $url.'backup/admin.min-bu.php');
        
        # write common functions
        $handle = fopen($url.'common.php', 'w+'); fwrite($handle, $common_functions); fclose($handle);  
        $handle = fopen($url.'common.min.php', 'w+'); fwrite($handle, $common_functions_min); fclose($handle);
        
        # write admin functions
        $handle = fopen($url.'admin.php', 'w+'); fwrite($handle, $admin_functions); fclose($handle);    
        $handle = fopen($url.'admin.min.php', 'w+'); fwrite($handle, $admin_functions_min); fclose($handle);
        
        
        $msg = 'All function files have been updated.'; 
    }
    
    //echo $msg;
    return $msg;
```

On the click, instead of parsing normally, an alert from the site sever is triggered that reads: *"You are not authorized to access this script"* as shown in the image below.
[image]

I have experienced this type of issue before about a year ago and found that adding the following code to the top of the php parsing file resolved the issue:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*');
```

**I also have tried to isolate the specific triggering file using this code:**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: url to specific triggering file,Vary: Origin');
```

**...and the actual woprdpress admin page:**

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: url to specific triggering wordpress admin page,Vary: Origin');
```

**None of the above have worked.**

I have the same code with different variables and parse files working fine on the same site in another plugin I developed. I am confused and in need of direction.

Comment: Given the information you have provided, we have no way of knowing what logic the JS is using before calling `alert()` with that message.

Comment: Thank you for your response Quentin. The parsing file returns a string message which in turn alerts the user the file has been parsed. This, however, is not the alert shown in the image as the alert in my js is only triggered by the return from the parse file which cannot occur because the server is denying access to the parse file and triggers the alert shown in the image.

Comment: I added the parsing file

Comment: Where are you defining ABSPATH? At the very top of your PHP it doesn't look like there are any includes or anywhere that defines ABSPATH, so **defined("ABSPATH")** will always be false

Comment: @imvain2... ABSPATH is defined constant by wordpress... I'm under the assumption that it is a global constant

Comment: @imvain2... that was the issue. thank you